# How to tell itemBuilder there is no more items in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

When going through the sample in [flutter tutorial](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/)

```
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  ...
  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

      itemBuilder: (context, i) {

        if (i.isOdd) return new Divider();

        final index = i ~/ 2;
        if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
          _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
        }
        return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to tell the `itemBuilder` that there are no more items. For example, I only want to show 30 items in the listview, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a property on this constructor called `itemCount`.

You can set it to whatever value you like to limit `ListView.builder`/`ListView.separated` size.

Here's an example a limits a `ListView` to 30 items

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 30,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(title: Text('index: $index'));
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: 30 item or 60 items?

Answer (score 2):

You just need `return null` in your itemBuilder function when there is no more item to build.

Comment: Tried this but Flutter raises this error: build function must never return null. The error also success to return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0). However returning an empty container causes a weird behavior, so avoid it.

Comment: Actually this happens to work in the current Flutter version! This is probably the best answer when the item count is unknown in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically stop the builder you just return null. However, you must use `ListView.custom` passing a delegate and inside it your nullable builder (`NullableIndexedWidgetBuilder`). `ListView.builder` expects a non-null builder (`IndexedWidgetBuilder`).

Hope this helps:

```
Widget buildList() {
  return ListView.custom(
    childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(itemBuilderFunction),
  );
}

Widget? itemBuilderFunction(BuildContext context, int i) {
  if (i.isOdd) {
    return const Divider();
  }

  final index = i ~/ 2;
  if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
    if (_suggestions.length < 100) { // limiting the list size to demonstrate
      _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
    }
  }

  if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
    return null;
  }

  return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
}
```